# Problems with ldap userCertificate attribute

Tags: certificates, openldap

I'm trying to use the 'userCertificate' attribute to hold a 'der' file.
I can happily add my certificate using the ldif:

> dn: cn=bob,ou=users,dc=home
>   changetype: modify
>   add: userCertificate;binary
>   userCertificate;binary:< file:///home/bob/cert.der

I see my certificate in base64 encoding when I do an ldapsearch and life seems good. But when I try to use ldapcompare:

> ldapcompare -D"cn=admin,dc=home" -W "cn=bob,ou=users,dc=home" "userCertificate;binary:< file:///home/bob/cert.der"

I get the error:

> Compare Result: Invalid syntax (21)
>   Additional info: unable to normalize value for matching
>   UNDEFINED

I get the same error if I try to compare using the base64 encoding

> ldapcompare -D"cn=admin,dc=home" -W "cn=bob,ou=users,dc=home" "userCertificate:: base64encodedStringOfStuff"

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if you already figured this out, but could your DER encoded certificate be corrupted somehow? This is working on my systems fine. The only difference is that I loaded the certificate into the ```usercertificate``` attribute as Base64 encoded (it wasn't DER encoded; I use PEM). Can you display the ```usercertificate ``` value as Base64 encoded using ```ldapsearch -LLL``` and compare the Base64 encoded value you use in ```ldapcompare```?

Comment: @Bora I spent two weeks trying to make this work and failed. I'd really appreciate it if you wrote down exactly what steps you took. i.e exact command to make certificate, exact command/ldif to load certificate into LDAP and exact command to do the ldapcompare. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm going to write it an answer as it allows me to use better formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just get this error: ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17) additional info: usercertificate: requires ;binary transfer.

This error message pretty clearly refers to what's mandated in [RFC 4523, section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4523#section-2.1). You simply always have to append `;binary` to the attribute name in all LDAP operations affecting attribute *userCertificate*.

> ldap_msgfree ldap_err2string Compare Result: Invalid syntax (21) Additional info: unable to normalize value for matching UNDEFINED

When using compare operation you have to look at which *EQUALITY* matching rule is available for the assertion attribute.

In subschema *userCertificate* is declared with `EQUALITY certificateExactMatch` based on issuer name and serial (see [RFC 4523 section 2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4523#section-2.5)) which means there's no pure octet string match available for that attribute.

So you need to extract the decimal serial number and the issuer DN (LDAP string representation) from the certificate:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -nameopt rfc2253 -serial -issuer -inform der -in ~/certs/michael@stroeder.com.cer 
serial=0F560E
issuer=CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Client CA,OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing,O=StartCom Ltd.,C=IL
```

Convert hex serial to decimal which is `1005070` in this example and invoke *ldapcompare* like this:

```
ldapcompare "cn=Michael Ströder+mail=michael@stroeder.com,dc=stroeder,dc=de" 'userCertificate;binary:{ serialNumber 1005070, issuer "cn=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Client CA,ou=Secure Digital Certificate Signing,o=StartCom Ltd.,c=IL"}'
TRUE
```

Additional notes:

- Be aware that DNs are complex beasts with escaping of special
  characters which need special treatment on shell command-line.
  Therefore I'd use a scripting language for this task to avoid
  some of the trouble.
- In opposite to modify operations and attribute retrieving you don't need the `;binary` transfer type for compare operation. But with OpenLDAP it won't hurt either. Not sure about other LDAP server implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but since it's 'pretty clear', that's what I've been doing. It doesn't work. my ldapcompare request does have ;binary in it. I've also tried Bora's ldapcompare with and without ;binary. No matter what I do I get the error: Compare Result: Invalid syntax (21)
Additional info: unable to normalize value for matching
UNDEFINED

Comment: Sorry, missed your compare issue. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've looked at the RFCs you linked and it's clear to me that I'm doing it wrong. But the RFCs may as well be written in Chinese. They're completely incomprehensible to me. I'd just like a command line example of how to do an ldapcompare on an X509 certificate. This seems to be way harder than I'd hoped.

Comment: It works. I can't even begin to imagine how you worked that out.

Comment: Well, many years PKI and LDAP...but I also had to use _certificateExactMatch_ in a Internet search to look up the assertion value syntax...

Answer (score 2):

Please note that I had a PEM encoded certificate, not a DER encoded one. You can use `openssl` to convert/display DER in PEM:

`openssl x509 -in /home/bob/cert.der -inform DER`

This command will display your certificate in PEM format. Something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I removed the top and the bottom lines just to have the Base64-encoded part. And, I executed the following command to load it into the `usercertificate` attribute:

```
$ ldapmodify -x -h my.ldap.server -Dcn=ADMIN_DN -W
Enter LDAP Password:

dn: uid=testuser,ou=users,o=foo.com    
changetype: modify
replace: usercertificate
usercertificate:: MIIDxTCCAq2gAwIBAgIQAqxcJmoLQJuPC3nyrkYldzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBsMQswCQYDVQQG
 EwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSsw
 KQYDVQQDEyJEaWdpQ2VydCBIaWdoIEFzc3VyYW5jZSBFViBSb290IENBMB4XDTA2MTExMDAwMDAw
 MFoXDTMxMTExMDAwMDAwMFowbDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEZ
 MBcGA1UECxMQd3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTErMCkGA1UEAxMiRGlnaUNlcnQgSGlnaCBBc3N1cmFu
 Y2UgRVYgUm9vdCBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMbM5XPm+9S75S0t
 Mqbf5YE/yc0lSbZxKsPVlDRnogocsF9ppkCxxLeyj9CYpKlBWTrT3JTWPNt0OKRKzE0lgvdKpVMS
 OO7zSW1xkX5jtqumX8OkhPhPYlG++MXs2ziS4wblCJEMxChBVfvLWokVfnHoNb9Ncgk9vjo4UFt3
 MRuNs8ckRZqnrG0AFFoEt7oT61EKmEFBIk5lYYeBQVCmeVyJ3hlKV9Uu5l0cUyx+mM0aBhakaHPQ
 NAQTXKFx01p8VdteZOE3hzBWBOURtCmAEvF5OYiiAhF8J2a3iLd48soKqDirCmTCv2ZdlYTBoSUe
 h10aUAsgEsxBu24LUTi4S8sCAwEAAaNjMGEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMB
 Af8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFLE+w2kD+L9HAdSYJhoIAu9jZCvDMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFLE+w2kD+L9HAdSY
 JhoIAu9jZCvDMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQAcGgaX3NecnzyIZgYIVyHbIUf4KmeqvxgydkAQ
 V8GK83rZEWWONfqe/EW1ntlMMUu4kehDLI6zeM7b41N5cdblIZQB2lWHmiRk9opmzN6cN82oNLFp
 myPInngiK3BD41VHMWEZ71jFhS9OMPagMRYjyOfiZRYzy78aG6A9+MpeizGLYAiJLQwGXFK3xPkK
 mNEVX58Svnw2Yzi9RKR/5CYrCsSXaQ3pjOLAEFe4yHYSkVXySGnYvCoCWw9E1CAx2/S6cCZdkGCe
 vEsXCS+0yx5DaMkHJ8HSXPfqIbloEpw8nL+e/IBcm2PN7EeqJSdnoDfzAIJ9VNep+OkuE6N36B9K

modifying entry "uid=testuser,ou=users,o=foo.com"

$
```

Note the leading single space in front of each Base64-encoded line. It's the continuation marker in LDIF. And, when I search using `ldapsearch`, I see:

```
$ ldapsearch -LLL -x -h my.ldap.server -Dcn=ADMIN_DN -W -b ou=users,o=foo.com uid=testuser usercertificate
Enter LDAP Password:

dn: uid=testuser,ou=users,o=foo.com  
userCertificate;binary:: MIIDxTCCAq2gAwIBAgIQAqxcJmoLQJuPC3nyrkYldzANBgkqhkiG9
 w0BAQUFADBsMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3
 cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSswKQYDVQQDEyJEaWdpQ2VydCBIaWdoIEFzc3VyYW5jZSBFViBSb290IEN
 BMB4XDTA2MTExMDAwMDAwMFoXDTMxMTExMDAwMDAwMFowbDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoT
 DERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEZMBcGA1UECxMQd3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTErMCkGA1UEAxMiRGlnaUNlc
 nQgSGlnaCBBc3N1cmFuY2UgRVYgUm9vdCBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCgg
 EBAMbM5XPm+9S75S0tMqbf5YE/yc0lSbZxKsPVlDRnogocsF9ppkCxxLeyj9CYpKlBWTrT3JTWPNt
 0OKRKzE0lgvdKpVMSOO7zSW1xkX5jtqumX8OkhPhPYlG++MXs2ziS4wblCJEMxChBVfvLWokVfnHo
 Nb9Ncgk9vjo4UFt3MRuNs8ckRZqnrG0AFFoEt7oT61EKmEFBIk5lYYeBQVCmeVyJ3hlKV9Uu5l0cU
 yx+mM0aBhakaHPQNAQTXKFx01p8VdteZOE3hzBWBOURtCmAEvF5OYiiAhF8J2a3iLd48soKqDirCm
 TCv2ZdlYTBoSUeh10aUAsgEsxBu24LUTi4S8sCAwEAAaNjMGEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMA8GA1U
 dEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFLE+w2kD+L9HAdSYJhoIAu9jZCvDMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFLE+
 w2kD+L9HAdSYJhoIAu9jZCvDMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQAcGgaX3NecnzyIZgYIVyHbIUf4K
 meqvxgydkAQV8GK83rZEWWONfqe/EW1ntlMMUu4kehDLI6zeM7b41N5cdblIZQB2lWHmiRk9opmzN
 6cN82oNLFpmyPInngiK3BD41VHMWEZ71jFhS9OMPagMRYjyOfiZRYzy78aG6A9+MpeizGLYAiJLQw
 GXFK3xPkKmNEVX58Svnw2Yzi9RKR/5CYrCsSXaQ3pjOLAEFe4yHYSkVXySGnYvCoCWw9E1CAx2/S6
 cCZdkGCevEsXCS+0yx5DaMkHJ8HSXPfqIbloEpw8nL+e/IBcm2PN7EeqJSdnoDfzAIJ9VNep+OkuE
 6N36B9K

$
```

I never got it working with the `< file:` directive against a DER or PEM file (without the `CERTIFICATE` markers). I'll do more investigation to see what's missing. However, if you reduce the multi-line the Base64-encoded certificate (PEM format) into a single line, then you can do the compare as

```
$ ldapcompare -x -Dcn=ADMIN_DN -W -h my.ldap.server uid=testuser,ou=users,o=foo.com 'usercertificate::MIIDxTCCAq2gAwIBAgIQAqxcJmoLQJuPC3nyrkYldzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBsMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSswKQYDVQQDEyJEaWdpQ2VydCBIaWdoIEFzc3VyYW5jZSBFViBSb290IENBMB4XDTA2MTExMDAwMDAwMFoXDTMxMTExMDAwMDAwMFowbDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEZMBcGA1UECxMQd3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTErMCkGA1UEAxMiRGlnaUNlcnQgSGlnaCBBc3N1cmFuY2UgRVYgUm9vdCBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMbM5XPm+9S75S0tMqbf5YE/yc0lSbZxKsPVlDRnogocsF9ppkCxxLeyj9CYpKlBWTrT3JTWPNt0OKRKzE0lgvdKpVMSOO7zSW1xkX5jtqumX8OkhPhPYlG++MXs2ziS4wblCJEMxChBVfvLWokVfnHoNb9Ncgk9vjo4UFt3MRuNs8ckRZqnrG0AFFoEt7oT61EKmEFBIk5lYYeBQVCmeVyJ3hlKV9Uu5l0cUyx+mM0aBhakaHPQNAQTXKFx01p8VdteZOE3hzBWBOURtCmAEvF5OYiiAhF8J2a3iLd48soKqDirCmTCv2ZdlYTBoSUeh10aUAsgEsxBu24LUTi4S8sCAwEAAaNjMGEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFLE+w2kD+L9HAdSYJhoIAu9jZCvDMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFLE+w2kD+L9HAdSYJhoIAu9jZCvDMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQAcGgaX3NecnzyIZgYIVyHbIUf4KmeqvxgydkAQV8GK83rZEWWONfqe/EW1ntlMMUu4kehDLI6zeM7b41N5cdblIZQB2lWHmiRk9opmzN6cN82oNLFpmyPInngiK3BD41VHMWEZ71jFhS9OMPagMRYjyOfiZRYzy78aG6A9+MpeizGLYAiJLQwGXFK3xPkKmNEVX58Svnw2Yzi9RKR/5CYrCsSXaQ3pjOLAEFe4yHYSkVXySGnYvCoCWw9E1CAx2/S6cCZdkGCevEsXCS+0yx5DaMkHJ8HSXPfqIbloEpw8nL+e/IBcm2PN7EeqJSdnoDfzAIJ9VNep+OkuE6N36B9K'
Enter LDAP Password:

TRUE
$
```

I'll update this if/when I can get it working with the `< file:` directive.

Comment: I just get this error: ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
 additional info: usercertificate: requires ;binary transfer. It can't be a problem with my certificate because I've also tried the one in your example.

Comment: Maybe I'll throw away all of my LDAP and start from scratch.

Comment: Started form scratch. It still doesn't work. I can only get ldapmodify to work if I use userCertificate;binary The ldapsearch command then works, but the ldapcompare command returns: Compare Result: Invalid syntax (21)
Additional info: unable to normalize value for matching
UNDEFINED

Comment: and that happens whether or not I add the ;binary. I guess I'm just cursed.

Comment: I can't really replicate this problem on my system which runs OpenLDAP ```2.4.45```. I also tried this against a directory powered by IBM Security Directory Server 6.4.0.15. It worked the same. The only thing I can think of is that the ```ldapcompare``` client you have is buggy (pure speculation on my part, of course). Can you paste the schema definition of the attribute ```usercertificate``` you have in your directory? I want to see if there's any difference.

Comment: I guess yours doesn't look like the below. I'm using Debian 9 and I've no idea what the ldap version is. The -V flag is not producing sensible information. It's clear that Debian have been messing around here. Here's my schema entry: # Must be transferred using ;binary
# with certificateExactMatch rule (per X.509)
attributetype ( 2.5.4.36 NAME 'userCertificate'
 DESC 'RFC2256: X.509 user certificate, use ;binary'
 EQUALITY certificateExactMatch
 SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.8 )

Comment: No, it looks exactly the same. I don't have Debian 9, but you should be able to list the package names and versions using ```dpkg-query -l```

Comment: 2.4.44, so not wildly different. If yours also says 'Must be transferred using ;binary' I wonder why you didn't need to?

Comment: Right, as shown in the output I pasted, ```ldapmodify``` didn't complain with the binary transfer. It's actually not ```ldapmodify``` that complains -- it's ```slapd```. What's baffling is that the ```slapd``` I'm running didn't complain with what I sent as the certificate. All the same, you got that working by tagging the attribute as ```binary```. What's not working now is ```ldapcompare```. Like I said, it's pure speculation, but I still think there's something wrong with the ```ldapcompare``` you have. Is it possible for you to test with a higher or even lower version of ```slapd```?

Comment: Also, can you turn on the debugging like this ```ldapcompare -v -d 65535 ....``` and see if it produces anything that may help?

Comment: Purged everything andI upgraded to 2.4.46 from debian stretch backports. It has made no difference.  I still get "Compare Result: Invalid syntax (21)
Additional info: unable to normalize value for matching
UNDEFINED" The debug output is gibberish to me but I've posted it in the question above (I chopped out large chunks of the output which just looked like a hexdump of the certificate). Thanks for your patience with this.